# Can You get Attachment Filenames from IMAP without Downloading them?

Tags: php, python, email, imap, attachment

Is there a way to check if an email has an attachment, and just get the filename without downloading it? In PHP, imap_fetchstructure() downloads the attachment to check it. Can this be done in PHP or Python?

Comment: Stucture shouldn't get the attachments themselves, just the description...

Comment: I would have thought that too, but it looks like it does download the attachment instead of just get the structure. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php#78076

Comment: I would call that a broken library.  The protocol very specifically supports fetching the structure via ``FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE)`` which will give you the name, encodings, content-types, etc. of all MIME parts of the message.